# Teaching stacks to differential geometry students

Tags: stacks, teaching, dg.differential-geometry

Does anyone have any experience teaching stacks over the category of manifolds to students whose background is, say, a semester-long course on manifolds?  Does anyone know of any publicly available notes on the subject, preferably in English?  [My French is limited to the knowledge of the alphabet :).  I can read Russian.]

I am aware of a paper by Behrend and Xu, Metzler's paper in the arxiv, and notes by Heinloth.  Hepworth has a nice exposition of vector fields on stacks, but his papers are rather terse.  Vistoli's notes on descent are quite nice, but are clearly aimed at algebraic geometers.  And there differences between the categories of manifolds and schemes --- fiber products of manifolds are badly behaved, for one thing.

The challenges in teachign such a course seem many.  For one thing I don't know how to talk about stacks without getting into 2-category theory.  And most differential geometers don't know much of 1-category theory.  But I don't want to start with a crash course on category theory.

Comment: One suggestion would be to limit yourself to orbifolds; then there are more resources available and teaching this to geometric topology students is not too difficult (in my experience). 

Comment: Have  looked at Weimin Chen's paper  "A homotopy theory of orbispaces"? http://front.math.ucdavis.edu/0102.5020

Comment: @Misha  Thank you for the suggestion.  But presenting orbifolds as topological spaces with extra structure kind of defeats the purpose of explaining how to think of them as stacks, doesn't it?

Comment: @Liviu  I had, when it first came out. I don't understand it.  

Comment: Hi Eugene. I have given some informal lectures about differentiable stacks to differential geometers a couple of times. I *might* be able to find some handwritten notes of mine from this. I also spend a good 100 pages or so giving a careful introduction to them in my thesis. (You can find a copy on my webpage: http://people.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/carchedi/)

Comment: Speaking as a differential geometer who, for the past 5 or so years, has wanted to learn about stacks for certain moduli space related reasons: I'm aware of the resources you've listed, and have found that there just isn't a treatment of differentiable stacks that even comes close to the resources available to algebraic geometers.  I think the fact that even in the setting of complex analytic stacks, the literature is very scarce, gives an impression of where the lines are drawn at this point in time.  If you come upon any better resources, or invent them yourself, I'd love to hear about it.

Comment: @LiviuNicolaescu the link in [your comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/118548/teaching-stacks-to-differential-geometry-students#comment304540_118548) is broken, here is a replacement: https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0102020

Comment: @DavidRoberts Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I had a good experience with Heinloth's notes. I tried to explain the two-categorical stuff
in the example of the stack of principal $G$-bundles. For example, a nice way to understand 2-pull-backs is to calculate $G\cong *\times_{BG}*$ explicitly. And of course, orbifolds and gerbes, e.g.
of $Spin^{c}$-reductions of a $Spin^{c}$-principal bundle  a provide examples accessible to differential geometers.